# Counting frequencies of the corresponding values in pandas [python 3]

Tags: python, pandas, count, cumulative-frequency

I have the dataset with the following values:

```
var1  var2 
1234  abc
2345  bcs
5678  csd
1234  abc
1234  bcs
5678  csd
1234  bcs
1234  xyz
1234  abc
9101  zzz
```

I need for every unique value in column var1 to count and show the top 3 frequency counts of the corresponding values in var2, and get the output, for example:

```
var1  var2  count
1234  abc   3
1234  bcs   2
1234  xyz   1
5678  csd   2
9101  zzz   1
```

What's the most efficient way of doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include `nlargest`

```
df.groupby('var1').var2.apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().nlargest(3)) \
    .reset_index(name='count').rename(columns={'level_1': 'var2'})

   var1 var2  count
0  1234  abc      3
1  1234  bcs      2
2  1234  xyz      1
3  2345  bcs      1
4  5678  csd      2
5  9101  zzz      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df_a.groupby(['var1','var2'])['var2'].agg({'count':'count'}).reset_index()
```

Comment: Scott, nice solution! adding count() at the end also worked, but having a count column at the end looks much better, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
df.groupby(['var1','var2']).count()
```